# A relation between $3-\sqrt 5$ and $\sqrt 5-1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, radicals, continued-fractions

Let $a=\sqrt{1+\cfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}}$ and let $b=\sqrt{1+\cfrac{\color{red}{\sqrt{5}-1}}{2}}$. Then $$\bigg(a+\frac 1a + b + \frac 1b\bigg)\bigg(a-\frac 1a+b-\cfrac 1b\bigg)=\color{blue}{3-\sqrt 5}.$$ Note that, curiously, $$\color{blue}{3-\sqrt 5} = \cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{4-\cfrac{1}{1+\ddots}}}\quad\text{and}\quad \color{red}{\sqrt 5 - 1}=\cfrac{1}{1-\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{1-\ddots}}}$$

Is there an explanation for these strange relationships? In fact, does this mean anything at all?

The structure of the continued fractions probably have to do with the following fact, which isn't too difficult to prove.

$$\frac 2a=\cfrac{1}{a+\cfrac{1}{b-\cfrac{1}{a+\ddots}}}+\cfrac{1}{a-\cfrac{1}{b+\cfrac{1}{a-\ddots}}}\tag*{$\forall a,b$}$$ If so, the continued fraction relationship between $3-\sqrt 5$ and $\sqrt 5 -1$ is merely a special case of the theorem above when $(a,b)=(1,4)$, in which the appearance of $\sqrt 5$ is related to the following similarly structured continued fractions. $$\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}=\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{1+\ddots}}}\quad\text{and}\quad \sqrt {5}=2+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{4+\ddots}}}$$ However, it all seems a bit too vague for my understanding. I'm sure I could find a way to relate every number to each other in maths, but are these relationships particularly special? To me, they definitely are of special *interest*, but that is subjective.

Comment: @downvoter May you explain why you down-voted? Is there something I could fix/improve as regards my question? Thanks.

Comment: What is the surprise finding relations between two numbers that sum to $2$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm talking about the relations in the post, collectively; particularly that a formula involving $\sqrt 5 - 1$ can yield $3-\sqrt 5$ in a symmetrical structure, just as how $3-\sqrt 5$ and $\sqrt 5 -1$ can be represented as continued fractions in the same sense of symmetrical form. I don't find this coincidental, as $\sqrt 5$ appears in an abundance of identities like this, especially when trigonometrically speaking.

Comment: You see symmetry where you injected it yourself.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How do you mean?

Comment: Note that $(\sqrt5-1)^2=2(3-\sqrt5)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Wow, thank you so much. I think you've struck the goldmine. I will happily accept that as an answer :)

Comment: @MrPie, what do you mean, 'trigonometrically speaking'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, the relation between them is $(\sqrt5-1)^2=2(3-\sqrt5)$.

Comment: Daily vote limit reached; will be able to up-vote from now in at least $12$ hours. That aside, congratulations! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually there's a typo at your first Eq,
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b}\right)\left(a-\frac{1}{a}+b-\frac{1}{b}\right)≠3-\sqrt{5}$$

The correct one will be,
$$\left(a+\frac{1}{a}+b+\frac{1}{b}\right)\left(a\color{red}{+}\frac{1}{a}\color{red}{-}b-\frac{1}{b}\right) \tag{1}$$

> Take $\varphi=(\sqrt{5}+1)/2$. We know $\varphi$ is a root of $x^2-x-1=0$. From this we can say that;
>   $$\varphi+1=\varphi^2\tag{2}$$
>   $$\varphi-1=1/\varphi=(\sqrt{5}-1)/2 \tag{3}$$

Your $a,b$ can be simplified as,
$$(a,b)=(\varphi,\sqrt{\varphi})$$
So Eq $1$, will be, (by solely using the relations $2,3$)
\begin{align}
& = \left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right)^{2}-\left(b+\frac{1}{b}\right)^{2} \\
 & = \left(2φ-1\right)^{2}-\left(\sqrt{φ}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{φ}}\right)^{2} \\ 
 & = 5-φ^{3} \\
 & = 5-\left(2φ+1\right) \\ 
 & = 2\left(2-φ\right) \\
\end{align}
Since, $φ=\frac{1}{φ}+1$,
\begin{align}
& = 2\left(1-\frac{1}{φ}\right) \\
 & = \frac{2}{φ^{2}} \\ 
 & = 2\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)^{2} \\
\end{align}

There's also no need for criminally expanding your question, when the answer you seek is just $2\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)^{2}$. Also it might be good to see other little or two things on golden ratio which can help like,

> $$φ^{n}=φ^{n-1}+φ^{n-2}$$ $$φ^{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n}φ$$
>   $$\sqrt{1+\sqrt{φ}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\sqrt[4]{φ^{3}}+\sqrt[4]{φ^{-3}}\right)$$
>   And etc. Where $F_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number, and $F_3=2$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for noticing that error, as well as including your other remarks; and thanks for an excellent answer. $(+1)$